# Python sending header with request issue

Tags: python, header, python-requests, discord.py

I'm having a small issue with sending a request with a custom header in order to use the fortnite tracker store within my discord bot.

The issue is that the url I get back tells me I haven't specified an API key when I open it, despite me passing it through as a header like is requested by the API.

I've tried quite a few variations of the code below e.g using requests.get rather than session.get and having the headers included within the 'r=' line but nothing seems to be working.

```
import requests
import discord


session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'TRN-Api-Key': 'Insert my API Key here'})
r = session.get('https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/store')
print(r.url)
imageURL = (r.url)
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url=imageURL)
await client.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the API documentation?

Comment: Perhaps try to do a curl request to see if it's an issue on their side?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh This is all there is for it: https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api

Comment: If this is gonna be in a discord bot command (or anything while the bot is effective), using requests module will be blocking, and you should aiohttp instead. See the docs [faq](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean).

Comment: Try running your request passing a `headers` argument: `get(url, headers={'TRN-Api-Key': 'Insert my API Key here'})` make sure the value is a string

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword Using aiohttp doesn't seem to work either. I set it to open a browser window with the requested url and I get the same No API key message.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Have tried that, also didn't work. I get the no api key message.

Comment: When I try that I get a `Invalid authentication credentials` (because I don't have a real key).  Is your `requests` up to date?  If you create a python file that just issues this request, does it also experience this problem?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I believe my requests is up to date and when I make a python file that just issues the request and then open the request in a browser I get the same thing '{"message":"No API key found in request"}'

Comment: @ConnorPrice I don't have Fortnite. But I was able to register a TRN account and then generate an API-Key. With `headers = {'TRN-Api-Key': key}`, `requests.get('https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/challenges', headers=headers)` worked fine. I get a 200 response and the text is JSON with the different challenges. Are you sure your API key is still valid? Did you provide a **valid** email adress?

EDIT: When creating my account and generating, I did not even have to check my inbox.

Comment: I was also able to perform it with aiohttp through my bot, but of course it requires you to be in an async context. I linked the [example](https://imgur.com/a/ahUHXyQ)

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword Hmm, not sure what's going on from my end then. I had thought that maybe my API key was the issue so I made another account and also had no luck with that new API key. I definitely used two different valid email addresses when creating an account and generating the key. I had aiohttp set up the same as you have in the example as well. Guess I'll have to email them and see if they know what's happening. Cheers for the help anyway.

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword Right, so I actually have it printing out the store to the console now but I'm struggling to get that data into a discord embed. https://imgur.com/a/T1FTWA3 That's the code I have. The embed I get on discord has the title, but then the description which is supposed to be lines 5-8 of the code is blank.

Comment: As you're using slicing, `desired_lines` is a list, but description should be a string. Use `'\n'.join(desired_lines)`

Comment: Though this method isn't good. This is JSON not simple text. Using `json.load(file)` or `json.loads(text)` would be much better, you would get a dict with the data.

Comment: Is this triggered by a not-owner command? If so, you shouldn't save the request as a file. Use BytesIO

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword I've actually ended up doing this a little different. My main concern now is getting the images to show up instead of just the link. Since embed thumbnail and embed image need a URL and these URL's will be constantly changing I'm not sure how to go about it. Discord.py doesn't recognise anything other than URL so I can't even extract the URL's to a dict and then send them that way.

Comment: which link? which image? Do you mean the rewardPicture? Because using JSON correctly, it will stay at the same [place](https://imgur.com/a/nCri3x8).

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword I'm using this to get the store rather than challenges so there are images with each item. I originally wanted to extract the URL's from the file (which I have) and then put that back into the discord embed to show the image in discord. But that's not possible as the embed will only take URL links. The URL's will change from day to day so they need to be taken either from a file or a dictionary or something.

Comment: This is why I'm telling you to use JSON as intended: https://imgur.com/a/690VStg
You just get all the informations you need from it ! Including the imageUrl.